# Error When Parsing Incoming Email Via SendGrid

Tags: json, django, parsing, webhooks, sendgrid

I am successfully set up a webhook with django/python to parse incoming SendGrid emails. However, I am getting an error and cannot parse the data I receive. The error suggest the body I am receiving is empty, which is not the case.

```
@csrf_exempt
def receive_email_hook(request):
  print("request.body: ",request.body)
  try: 
    data = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
    sender = data['from']
    recipient = data['to']
    subject = data['subject']
    body = data['html']
    print("SUBJECT: "+str(subject))
    return HttpResponse(status=200)
  except Exception as e:
    print("ERROR: "+str(e))
    return HttpResponse(status=400)
```

My error is:

```
ERROR: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

When I print the request.body, I get:

```
request.body:  b'--xYzZY\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="headers"\r\n\r\nReceived: (...)
```

The full print has all the information from the email and all the data I would expect. Just seems to be an error on the parsing but can't figure it out. I asked Chat GPT but got some whack ass answers, so fellow human, can you help?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it:

```
@csrf_exempt
def receive_email_hook(request):
  envelope = json.loads(request.POST.get('envelope'))
  to_address = envelope['to'][0]
  from_address = envelope['from']

  # Now, onto the body
  subject = request.POST.get('subject')
  text = request.POST.get('text')
```

Converted from SendGrid's Flask example: https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/tracking-events/python-code-example